# Postgres Remote Access

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea

My teammate can't access to my Database on PgAdmin. I have connected the database on IntelliJ. 
That's what i see: 
[image: IntelliJ-MyView (i'm the localhost)]
That's what my teammate see:
[image]
Under postgres>schemas>public 
He can only see Student table.

On the file postgresql.conf I already have replaced the line listen_addresses = 'localhost' with listen_addresses= '*'

[image]

And on the file pg_hba.conf that's the situation:
[image]

Why he cant see all the tables? How can we fix it? 
We need that from his pc he can access to my database. 
Thanks for help and orry for bad english.

Comment: You tagged pgAdmin and wrote pgAdmin but the screenshot from your mate doesn't show pgAdmin. Do you both use the same login/role?

Comment: He didnt do nothing on his pgAdmin, he need to do something? There's only one role and it's called "postgres"

Comment: He should try with pgAdmin first. That can rules out whether it's a third party program problem.

Comment: How can he connect to my local database by pgadmin? I'm searching online but I can't find nothing..

Comment: He tried by cmd using:   psql - h xxx.xxx.xx.xxx(IP where is located in local the dB) - U postgres -p 5432
It doesn't work, postgres doesn't allow the connection. Port 5432 is listening for TCP/IP, netstats shows it. Listen addresses is set to * and there isn't the # before it.
Why he can't connect to my dB?

Comment: Check the `pg_hba.conf` if there's any matching rule before the rule that should allow access. And don't forget to restart the server, when you do changes in the configuration.

Comment: Im restarting server using 
pg_ctl -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\data" restart
After it the prompt said: 
pg_ctl: the file PID "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/data/postmaster.pid" doesnt exists
The server is in execution?
the server is starting anyway..
server is starting..